# How do I concat two jsons in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to put a list of array json into one of the json arrays but my attempts doesnt work the way I wanted to. Here is my attempts.

```
import json
import uuid
from datetime import datetime

accountIds = [12345,56789]
members= {"L": []}
for accountId in accountIds:
    members["L"].append({"M": {"memberType": {"S": "account"}}},
    {"M": {"memberId": {"S": accountId}}},
    {"M": {"history": {"L": [
    {"M": {"startDate": ""}},
    {"M": {"endDate": ""}}]}}})

    
group = {
    "pk": {"S": str(uuid.uuid4())},
    "pkType": {"S": "pk"},
    "client": {"S": '123'},
    "groupName": {"S": 'abc'},
    "createdDate": {"S": datetime.today().isoformat()},
    "modifiedDate": {"S": datetime.today().isoformat()},
    "status": {"S": "active"},
    "Members": {"L": [members]}
        }
print(json.dumps(group));
```

This is my desired outcome.

```
{
   "pk":{
      "S":"9c1fbd69-274f-4b9e-be30-3f8f9a00e0ac"
   },
   "pkType":{
      "S":"pk"
   },
   "client":{
      "S":"123"
   },
   "groupName":{
      "S":"abc"
   },
   "createdDate":{
      "S":"2021-05-17T10:06:22.622634"
   },
   "modifiedDate":{
      "S":"2021-05-17T10:06:22.622668"
   },
   "status":{
      "S":"active"
   },
   "Members":{
      "L":[{
         {
            "M":{
               "memberType":{
                  "S":"account"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "M":{
               "memberId":{
                  "S":"12345"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "M":{
               "history":{
                  "L":[
                     {
                        "M":{
                           "startDate":""
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "M":{
                           "endDate":""
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }},
         {
         {
            "M":{
               "memberType":{
                  "S":"account"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "M":{
               "memberId":{
                  "S":"6789"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "M":{
               "history":{
                  "L":[
                     {
                        "M":{
                           "startDate":""
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "M":{
                           "endDate":""
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }}
      ]
   }
}
```

Please note that under `Members`
below count as one object in the array
{{
"M": {
"memberType": {
"S": "account"
}
}
},
{
"M": {
"memberId": {
"S": accountId
}
}
},
{
"M": {
"history": {
"L": [
{
"M": {
"startDate": ""
}
},
{
"M": {
"endDate": ""
}
}
]
}
}
}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about merging two dictionaries first and then dump the merged dictionary to json. We can merge two dictionaries like below:

`merged_dict = {**dict1, **dict2}`

Example:

```
import json

a = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 3
}

b = {
    "D": 4,
    "E": 5
}

c = {**a, **b}

print(json.dumps(c))
```

It prints

```
{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4, "E": 5}
```

**Update**

In this particular case as mentioned in the comment we don't really need to merge two dictionaries. Changing `"Members": {"L": [members]}` to `"Members": members` should do the trick. However exact format will not be possible to achieve as in here we are trying to serialise a `Set`. `Serialising` a set is not possible inside json and it will throw an error. So our best bet here is a list. Modified code is given below.

```
import json
import uuid
from datetime import datetime

accountIds = [12345, 56789]
members = {"L": []}
for accountId in accountIds:
    members["L"].append([{"M": {"memberType": {"S": "account"}}}, #Added square bracket to make it a list
                        {"M": {"memberId": {"S": accountId}}},
                        {"M": {"history": {"L": [
                            {"M": {"startDate": ""}},
                            {"M": {"endDate": ""}}]}}}])

group = {
    "pk": {"S": str(uuid.uuid4())},
    "pkType": {"S": "pk"},
    "client": {"S": '123'},
    "groupName": {"S": 'abc'},
    "createdDate": {"S": datetime.today().isoformat()},
    "modifiedDate": {"S": datetime.today().isoformat()},
    "status": {"S": "active"},
    "Members": members} # modified from "Members": {"L": [members]}
print(json.dumps(group));
```

It prints

```
{
    "pk": {
        "S": "814c2fb9-8afd-499c-b98a-592b53bb9ca5"
    },
    "pkType": {
        "S": "pk"
    },
    "client": {
        "S": "123"
    },
    "groupName": {
        "S": "abc"
    },
    "createdDate": {
        "S": "2021-05-17T18:35:04.388906"
    },
    "modifiedDate": {
        "S": "2021-05-17T18:35:04.388906"
    },
    "status": {
        "S": "active"
    },
    "Members": {
        "L": [
            [
                {
                    "M": {
                        "memberType": {
                            "S": "account"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "M": {
                        "memberId": {
                            "S": 12345
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "M": {
                        "history": {
                            "L": [
                                {
                                    "M": {
                                        "startDate": ""
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "M": {
                                        "endDate": ""
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "M": {
                        "memberType": {
                            "S": "account"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "M": {
                        "memberId": {
                            "S": 56789
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "M": {
                        "history": {
                            "L": [
                                {
                                    "M": {
                                        "startDate": ""
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "M": {
                                        "endDate": ""
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

We can access individual objects as mentioned in the question by iterating over `group["Members"]["L"]` like below:

```
for item in group["Members"]["L"]:
    print(item)
```

It prints

```
[{'M': {'memberType': {'S': 'account'}}}, {'M': {'memberId': {'S': 12345}}}, {'M': {'history': {'L': [{'M': {'startDate': ''}}, {'M': {'endDate': ''}}]}}}]
[{'M': {'memberType': {'S': 'account'}}}, {'M': {'memberId': {'S': 56789}}}, {'M': {'history': {'L': [{'M': {'startDate': ''}}, {'M': {'endDate': ''}}]}}}]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Roy, but the problem is that under members there are two "L" it should be one array [ { "M" } under it. Not array of array. I updated description

Comment: In that case we need to add individual dictionaries to the list. `{{"M":"N"},{"O":"P"}}` as mentioned in the question, is not a legal dictionary. I have just replaced the outer curly braces with square brace since it seemed like a list.

Comment: I see, but how do I add individual dictionaries to the list?

Comment: I guess a made a mistake understanding OP's question. Just chainging `"Members": {"L": [members]}` to `"Members": members` should do the job.

Comment: We need to invoke `members["L"].append(<dictionary>)` for each dictionary item we want to append. In the original code we have just single append with multiple dictionaries inside curly braces.

Comment: would you mind show me an example? I got TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when I attempted to append a dict

Comment: I have modified the answer. If that resolves your query, please mark this as Answer. In case you need further clarification, do let me know. Thanks